# find win32api.py for jython application

Tags: python-2.7, jython, pywin32

I work on a jython project and I need the win32api.py library. In effect jython does not read compiled libraries (.pyd)
Is it possible to find the win32api.py library?
thank you

Comment: Is `ctypes` package available in Jython?

Comment: And which Win32 API functions do you need?

Comment: I use the openOPC  library. The latter uses the pywin32 library. This works well in python , but when I import it into my jython project  it does not find the win32api beaucause this library is in .pyd format

Comment: It seems Jython doesn't support pyWin32 at all.

Comment: Ok i'm find a other solution, fine